# Why is Spring Security CSRF check failing when using MockMVC MockMvc

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-mvc-test

Sorry for the information overload, I would think that a lot more information is here than needed.

So I have this test code

```java
package com.myapp.ui.controller.user;

import static com.myapp.ui.controller.user.PasswordResetController.PASSWORD_RESET_PATH;
import static com.myapp.ui.controller.user.PasswordResetController.ResetPasswordAuthenticatedDto;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.NullAndEmptySource;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.web.SpringJUnitWebConfig;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.myapp.db.liquibase.LiquibaseService;
import com.myapp.sample.ModelBuilderFactory;

@ComponentScan( "com.myapp.ui")
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(  classes = { LiquibaseService.class, ControllerTestBaseConfig.class }  )
public class PasswordResetControllerTest  {

    @Autowired
    private ModelBuilderFactory mbf;

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private String username;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup( WebApplicationContext wac) throws Exception {
        username = mbf.siteUser().get().getUsername();
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( wac )
            .apply( SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity() )
            .defaultRequest( get( "/" ).with( user(username) ) )
            .alwaysDo( print() )
            .build();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @NullAndEmptySource
    @ValueSource(strings = "abcd")
    void testPasswordResetInvalidate( String password ) throws Exception {
        ResetPasswordAuthenticatedDto dto = new ResetPasswordAuthenticatedDto( username, password );

        RequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.patch( PASSWORD_RESET_PATH )
            .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
            .content( mapper.writer().writeValueAsString( dto ) );

        mockMvc.perform( builder )
            .andExpect( MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNoContent() );
    }

}
```

This is the relevant debug output

```
[INFO ] PATCH /ui/authn/user/password-reset for user null (session 1, csrf f47a7f39-c310-4e5d-a4be-cc9bd120229f) with session cookie (null) will be validated against CSRF [main] com.myapp.config.MyCsrfRequestMatcher.matches(MyCsrfRequestMatcher.java:76) 
[DEBUG] Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost/ui/authn/user/password-reset            [main] org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:127) 
[DEBUG] Starting new session (if required) and redirecting to '/login?error=timeout'          [main] org.springframework.security.web.session.SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy.onInvalidSessionDetected(SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy.java:49) 
[DEBUG] Redirecting to '/login?error=timeout'                                                 [main] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy.sendRedirect(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:54) 
[DEBUG] Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@4b367665 [main] org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter.writeHeaders(HstsHeaderWriter.java:169) 
[DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed                    [main] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:119) 

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = PATCH
      Request URI = /ui/authn/user/password-reset
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json", Content-Length:"68"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@55b1156b, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@12919b87: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@12919b87: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@1e05232c: Username: lab_admin4oyc8tkytxu4zllguk-1qg; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"SAMEORIGIN", Location:"/login?error=timeout"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = /login?error=timeout
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<204> but was:<302>
Expected :204
Actual   :302
```

This is our relevant `SecurityConfig`

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext ctx = getApplicationContext();
        http
            .addFilterAfter( ctx.getBean( TimeoutFilter.class ), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class )
            .addFilterAt( ctx.getBean( "myLogoutFilter", LogoutFilter.class ), LogoutFilter.class )
            .addFilterBefore( ctx.getBean( IpAddressAuditFilter.class ), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class )
            .addFilterAt( ctx.getBean( MyConcurrentSessionFilter.class ), ConcurrentSessionFilter.class )
            .addFilterAfter( ctx.getBean( RequestLogFilter.class ), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class )
            .headers().xssProtection().and().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/styles/**.css",
                "/fonts/**",
                "/scripts/**.js",
                "/VAADIN/**",
                "/jsp/**",
                "/*.css",
                "/help/**",
                "/public/error/**"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers( "/app/**", "/downloads/**", "/ui/authn/**" ).fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(
                "/login**",
                "/register/**",
                "/public/**",
                "/sso_logout",
                "/sso_auth_failure",
                "/sso_concurrent_session",
                "/sso_timeout"
            ).anonymous()
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage( "/login" )
            .loginProcessingUrl( SecurityConstants.loginPath() )
            .defaultSuccessUrl( "/app", true )
            .failureUrl( "/login?error=badCredentials" )
            .usernameParameter( SecurityConstants.usernameField() )
            .passwordParameter( SecurityConstants.passwordField())
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler( new MyAccessDeniedHandler() )
            .authenticationEntryPoint( new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint( "/login" ) )
            .and()
            .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher( csrfRequestMatcher )
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession().invalidSessionUrl( "/login?error=timeout" )
            .maximumSessions( 1 ).sessionRegistry( sessionRegistry )
            .expiredUrl( "/login?error=concurrentSession"  );
    }
```

The test is redirecting to `timeout` because it see's the session as invalid.

we are using the the spring boot parent BOM *only* for dependency management, we have not yet converted to spring boot (WIP). Information included so you know what versions we're on.

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>
```

Given that I'm using the spring security `user()` and `springSecurity()` for setting up the MockMvc, I'm not certain why the CSRF isn't right. I added my path to the paths that we exclude when checking for CSRF, and this problem went away. What would I need to do to get have the CSRF check pass?

Comment: "We have a custom CSRF matcher that I can't share here" - so you have code you cannot share and you ask why is it not working?

Comment: @eis all the CsrfRequestMatcher does is say "should we validate the CSRF" yes or no, it returns a boolean in this case it's obviously returning `true`, which is correct. Although I've udpated the question because I set it to `false` and this problem goes away (and a whole new problem arises). I'm removing that statement, it's irrelevant. also that matcher has been in production for years, this is only a problem in the MockMvc test that I'm writing. The real context works fine.

Comment: have you tried `mockMvc.perform(builder).with( SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf())`? or does adding secure flag with `mockMvc.perform(builder).secure( true )` change anything?

Comment: or if it's supposed to get in through a header, `.with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf().asHeader()))`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you're generating a CSRF token for your request anywhere in your test. Logs do show you have some CSRF token in there, but if you're not providing such token in a request, CsrfFilter will create you one and will compare to that one, which I would expect to fail in a manner you reported.

You can create a csrf token for mockMvc request by giving `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf()` as a parameter for `mockMvc.perform(builder).with( ...  )`.

To examine if you have a csrf token in your request, I'd run this through a debugger and place a breakpoint [around the lines 120-123 of CsrfFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfFilter.java#L120-L123).